# C#: SocketException when Server closes?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently receiving a strange error, and want to handle it for 1 specific case. When the server closes and the client is still connected to it, the client will throw an exception

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host'

I know how to handle this, a try and catch, but am I handling more than one reason this exception would be thrown here? I just want to handle it if the server closes, not all of the other reasons this exception may suddenly occur. Can anybody help here?

What line is the error occuring on?

```
var bytesReceived = _socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
```

What method?

```
private void OnIncomingData(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Method content

```
var bytesReceived = _socket.EndReceive(asyncResult);

try
{
    var packet = new byte[bytesReceived];
    Array.Copy(_buffer, packet, bytesReceived);

    var received = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(packet);
    CoreUtilities.LogToConsole("Received data: " + received);
}
catch
{
    Dispose();
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        _socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnIncomingData, _socket);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error handling and resource mgmt are very confusing. Are you really using try/finally to loop? And are those empty catch blocks literal?

Comment: "Forcibly closed" means an `RST` packet was sent over the line because the server rudely slammed the connection shut, and it's not a usual occurrence. If the server cleanly closes the socket (by `using` its resources properly or explicitly calling `.Shutdown`), it won't happen. But that's not something you, as the client, can influence. You'll have to handle the exception in any case, for the simple reason that the socket is no longer usable when this happens. Whether it happens because the server's badly written or it had a hard crash isn't your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle this using the `SocketErrorCode` property which part of [SocketException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception(v=vs.110).aspx). According to this [TechNET](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187005%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article (I couldn't find anything on MSDN), the error code should be 10054 which matches with the `SocketError.ConnectionReset` enum value as shown below:

[image]

Example of handling the specific error:

```
 try
 {
    _socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnIncomingData, _socket);
 }
 catch (SocketException ex)
 {
    if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionReset)
    {
       //Do Something
    }
 }
```

Comment: `else { throw; }` ?? Thanks for this!

Comment: Yeah that would work but check the error codes because all would slip through apart from connection reset. If your happy with that then go for it.